# Misra-C 2012 rule 10.1 boolean operand to be used in case where expression is of boolean type

Tags: c, misra

The following lines generate misra violations.

```
unsigned int u16_a;
unsigned char u8_b;  
if (u16_a && u8_b) // Generates Misra-C 10.1 violation. 
(u16_a) ? 2 : 1 //Generates Misra-C 10.1 violation.
```

The violation says the operand is of essential signed type but should be of boolean type.

For the 1st violation, If I type cast them to _Bool type, will it not result in overflow since I remember size of bool datatype is 1 byte.

For the 2nd violation tried this:

```
(u16_a == 0)? 1 :2 // does this work
```

I'm pretty new in dealing MISRA violations and confused with most of the violations.
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What are the types of `u16_a` and `u8_a`?

Comment: Sorry , will edit the question. u16_a refers to unsigned int_16 , u8_a refers to unsigned char

Comment: Can you declare them as _Bool?

Comment: You can't cast _to_ `_Bool` because `_Bool` assumes that true = value 1.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, MISRA-C wants us to treat logical/relational operators as if they returned a bool type (like in C++) and generally "pretend" that C has a distinct bool type that is separate from integers. This gives increased type safety when you use static analysis tools.

Which means that you have to be explicit with checks against zero:

```
if ( (u16_a!=0u) && (u8_b!=0u) )
```

and

```
(u16_a!=0) ? 2u : 1u
```

Or preferably something more readable:

```
bool b_a = u16_a!=0u;
bool b_b = u8_b!=0u;

if(b_a && b_b) // MISRA compliant, operands are essentially boolean types
```

Comment: Will this ( (u16_a!=0u) && (u8_b!=0u) ) not result in MISRA 10.4 violation. Since u16_a is essentially unsigned int 16 bit while 0u is unsigned 8 bit

Comment: @prime130392 The result of `!=` is always of type `int`. Both operands of the `&&` will therefore be `int`. (Though according to MISRA, essentially boolean)

Answer (score 3):

Use
`if ( (u16_a !=0u) && (u8_b != 0u) )`
instead of
`if (u16_a && u8_b)`
for the first example.

For the latter:
`(u16_a == 0)? 1 :2` seems to be ok to me.

Bottom line is that the whole point of this MISRA requirement is: "specify explicitly when comparing against a value, instead of relying on the defaults".

Comment: Thanks. For the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

The C standard says:

> 6.3.1.2 Boolean type
>
> 1 When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.

So casting to _Bool does the right thing. `(x != 0)` may be more readable than `((_Bool)x)` though.