# MISRA violation of ternary operator in C code

Tags: c, boolean, typedef, conditional-operator, misra

I have run the MISRA for the below code written in C. I have a ternary operator to find the input type. This is the piece of code I have written.

```
typedef enum{
    type0 = 0,
    type1,
    type2
}my_values;

#define get_type() (uint8)((bool_type0()) ? (type0) : ( (bool_type1()) ?  type1 : type2  ))

/* Here bool_type0() and bool_type1() are outside functions which return bool values */

function1 ()
{
    uint8 type_value = 0U;

    type_value = get_type();

    if((type_value == type0) || (type_value == type1 ))
    {
        //update the logic
    }
    else
    {
        //update the logic
    }
}
```

After running the MISRA, I am getting the warnings below:

1. In this line `type_value = get_type();` I am getting warning as

   First operand to a ternary operator has an inappropriate essential type ‘unsigned char’
2. In the if loop, I am getting warnings as

   The operand of the operator ‘==’ do not have the same essential type category: one is ‘unsigned’ and other is ‘enum’

I didn't understand what is wrong with the 1st warning. In the 2nd warning, how can I change the enum to an unsigned value? I guess I have to change both operands to unsigned values. Without changing the enum type, how can I fix these errors? Any suggestion?

Comment: Why isn't `#define get_type()` a function? (`A function should be used  in preference to a function-like macro where they are interchangeable`)

Comment: You need to show how the two functions are declared

Comment: Why not declare `type_value` as `my_values` instead of `uint8`? I don;t think you should need the casts to `(unint8)` in the macro, either.

Comment: The answer seems to be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131637/misra-c-2012-rule-10-1-boolean-operand-to-be-used-in-case-where-expression-is-of

Comment: If you're using MISRA because you want to ensure clear, maintainable code, I would strongly consider getting rid of the nested `?:` operators, and replacing them with a simple nested `if/else` statement which any later reader can understand at a glance.

Comment: I agree with @SteveSummit and MISRA also got a whole lot of rules related to function-like macros, so stay clear of those as well, unless you truly must use them.

Comment: Spot on, Lundin... inline the code and it's clearer what you are trying to do, and avoids unexpected expansion issues...

Comment: Only the one Rule... don't use them :-)

Answer (score 1):

> First operand to a ternary operator has an inappropriate essential type ‘unsigned char’

The first operand needs to be boolean. Your tool doesn't realize what type that corresponds to boolean in in your code.

Every static analyser for MISRA-C needs to be configured so that it knows which type that is the boolean type, since it is backwards-compatible with C90 that didn't have boolean types. It's pretty bad that you have to do this if you are using `bool` or `_Bool`, but that's how the tool you picked works, apparently.

> The operand of the operator ‘==’ do not have the same essential type category : one is ‘unsigned’ and other is ‘enum’

This is a correct diagnostic, you shouldn't be comparing enum (enumeration variables or enumeration constants) against integer values for MISRA-C compliance, only with their own enum type. You need to study the rules for essential type in MISRA-C:2012 to understand this, there's a handy table where you can see which types that can/can't be used together with which other types for a certain operator.

It's easy enough to fix: `(my_values)type_value == type0`.

Comment: Agreed - I'm guessing `bool` is the standards `typedef unsigned char` so the MISRA checker is seeing an `unsigned char` (without a `== false` or `!= true`) and doesn't know it is (meant to be) a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down...

1. You are declaring/defining `type_value` as a `uint8`

`uint8 type_value = 0U;`

2. Then you are using that messy macro...

   #define get_type() (uint8)((bool_type0()) ? (type0) : ( (bool_type1()) ?  type1 : type2  ))

   /* Here bool_type0() and bool_type1() are outside functions which return bool values */

   type_value = get_type();

So lets expand the macro...

```
type_value = (uint8)( ( bool_type0() )
           ? ( type0 )
           : ( ( bool_type1() ) ? type1 : type2 ) )
```

Firstly, why is `type_value` a `uint8` when it is containing values from the enumeration... declare it as `enum my_values`

Other than that, I see nothing obviously wrong, part from the unnecessary and confusing macro.

```
enum my_values type_value = bool_type0() ? type0 : ( bool_type1() ? type1 : type2 );
```

this suggests that your tool is not correctly configured for detecting boolean... and is treating `bool` (actually `uint8_t`, which is an `unsigned char`) as an, err, `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I'd write it.

```
typedef enum{
    type0 = 0,
    type1,
    type2
} my_values;

/* Here bool_type0() and bool_type1() are outside functions which return bool values */
my_values get_type(void)
{
    my_values ret_val = type2;
    
    if (bool_type0())
    {
        ret_val = type0;
    } 
    else if (bool_type1())
    {
        ret_val = type1;
    } 
    else
    { 
        /* no need, type2 by default */
    }

    return ret_val;
}

function1 ()
{
    my_values type_value = get_type();

    if((type_value == type0) || (type_value == type1 ))
    {
        //update the logic
    }
    else
    {
        //update the logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Most likely a false positive reported by your linter.

A handful of shot in the dark guesses to make the linter happy.

1. Try forcing all elements of the ternary to be uint8:

Define your macros as this:

```
#define get_type() (bool_type0() ? (uint8)type0 : bool_type1() ? (uint8)type1 : (uint8)type2)
```

2. Could be the the `=0` in the enum declaration is throwing it off.  Try declaring the enum without it:

This:

```
typedef enum{
    type0,  // should default to 0
    type1,
    type2
}my_values;
```

Or all explicit:

```
typedef enum{
    type0 = 0,
    type1 = 1,
    type2 = 2
}my_values;
```

3. Finally, I'm surprised you aren't getting a warning about `function1` not having a definitive return type.  I'm wondering if the lack of a return type specified in your function definition is throwing the linter off.  Mark it explicitly as having a void return type:

Try this:

```
void function1()
{
     ....
```

Comment: still getting warning "First operand to a ternary operator has an inappropriate essential type ‘unsigned char" in the `type_value = get_type();` line.

Comment: "Try forcing all elements of the ternary to be uint8:" No, this is wrong. Also the way the conditional operator works, the 2nd and 3rd operand are balanced as per the usual arithemtic conversions, so your casts achieve nothing, save for introducing another MISRA-C violation - now the code has implicit promotions suddenly, it didn't before those casts.

Comment: "Could be the the =0 in the enum declaration is throwing it off" No, that has nothing to do with the MISRA violation. You simply aren't allowed to compare variables of different essential type categories. The only way to understand this is to read the MISRA-C document. The TL;DR is basically: it is fine to have implicit conversions if both operands are signed or both are unsigned, but not if they are mixed or change signedness as per some implicit conversion.

Comment: In general, you can't resolve these warnings with trial & error. "Cast and see if it works" isn't a professional approach. C programmers have to learn the various implicit type promotion rules and the many dangers that come with them. Implicit promotions are perhaps some of the biggest flaws of the language.