# Misra 2012 Rule 10.1

Tags: c, misra

Below C code has QAC violation - MISRA 2012 Rule 10.1

```
sLhsStatesInfo->ucLhsMssgCntr = ((Pack_Array_2[4] & (uint8)0xF0)>>4);
```

Error msg: A non-negative constant expression of 'essentially signed' type(signed char) is being used as the right-hand operand of this shift operator (>>). Misra C:2012 Rule-10.1

Can anyone suggest what's going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: You could try `4u` to make it unsigned.

Comment: Frankly, the MISRA rule checker is being stupid.

Comment: I agree it's a stupid rule.  But here's the rationale: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44132801/421195

Comment: @paulsm4: How is that related to the right-hand side of the shift operator?

Comment: @paulsm4 No that link has nothing to do with the reasons for this rule. 10.1 serves to protect against left shifting into sign bits (undefined behavior), right shifting negative numbers (impl.defined behavior), shifting out of range (undefined behavior) or shifting with a negative shift count (undefined behavior, possibly also constraint violation(?)).

Comment: It's a tool bug. There is no signed char anywhere in this expression. `4` is essentially signed type `int`.

Answer (score 5):

Clearly your tool vendor has not read MISRA C:2012 Rule 10.1, which has an exception:

> **Exception**
> A non-negative integer constant expression of essentially signed type
> may be used as the right hand operand to a shift operator.

It is a false positive... flag it with your tool vendor.  In the interim add a comment (or similar) to your code to highlight it is a false positive.

See profile for affiliation

Comment: 10.1 is very confusing. If looking at the table further up, then we come up with "7. The right hand operand of a shift operator should be of _essentially unsigned type_ to ensure that undefined behaviour does not result from a negative shift." This is just a few rows above the exception you quoted and wildly contradicting but equally normative text.

Comment: I also missed that exception in the past. For variables #7 makes sense but for literals such a rule is nonsense. Unfortunately both Coverity and cppcheck already reported such code as issues. ...beside even worse nonsense. ;)

Comment: @Lundin - a *variable* should of unsigned type, but a literal doesn't matter